# Embedded database in DynamicWeb project

Tags: java, database, web-applications

How can I realize an embedded database in my WebApp project?  So, to test the project I use Tomcat. Is there a way that I can have a "local" / standalone database in a webapplication?

My local db (db.script):

```
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB56C1DBAB62
SET DATABASE GC 0
SET DATABASE DEFAULT RESULT MEMORY ROWS 0
SET DATABASE EVENT LOG LEVEL 0
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS
SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON CONFLICT TRUE
SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS ''
SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL REFERENCES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL SIZE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL AVG SCALE 0
SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE
SET FILES WRITE DELAY 500 MILLIS
SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT TRUE
SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000
SET FILES SCALE 32
SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
SET FILES DEFRAG 0
SET FILES NIO TRUE
SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
SET FILES LOG TRUE
SET FILES LOG SIZE 50
CREATE USER "Chris" PASSWORD DIGEST '4a7d1ed414474e4033ac29ccb8653d9b'
ALTER USER "Chris" SET LOCAL TRUE
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.CUSTOMER(ID VARCHAR(20))
ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC
GRANT DBA TO "Chris"
SET SCHEMA SYSTEM_LOBS
INSERT INTO BLOCKS VALUES(0,2147483647,0)
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('CHRIS')
```

Here is my Java class to conenct to the database (only a test class):

```
package jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 * Dies Klasse liefert eine  JDBC Connection zurück
 * @author Christian
 *
 */
public class JDBCConnector {

    private Connection connection;

    public JDBCConnector(String url, String user, String password){
        try{
          Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
          if(connection != null){
              System.out.println("Verbindung hergestellt");
          }
        }catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ){
            System.err.println("Der Datenbanktreiber konnte nicht geladen werden");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Beim Erstellen der Verbindung ist ein Feheler aufgetreten.\n"
                    + "Bitte überprüfen Sie die URL, sowie Usernamen und Passwort");
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
        if(connection != null){
            return connection;
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Connection == null");
        }
    } 

    public String getFirstEntry(){
        try {
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER");
            String s = "";
            while(rs.next()){
                s = rs.getString(1);
                System.out.println("s: " + s);
            }
            return s;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }


}
```

And here is the JSP file, which is called to connect to the database:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="jdbc.JDBCConnector"  %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% JDBCConnector connector = new JDBCConnector("jdbc:hsqldb:file:/Gefaehrdungsbeurteilung_Full/gefaehrdungsbeurteilung_full/server/db/db", "Chris", "0000"); 
    out.append(connector.getFirstEntry());
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

And if I execute, I get the following error:

```
Verbindung hergestellt
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: CUSTOMER
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at jdbc.JDBCConnector.getFirstEntry(JDBCConnector.java:45)
    at org.apache.jsp.gefaehrdungsbeurteilung_005ffull.server.jsp.Access_jsp._jspService(Access_jsp.java:121)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: CUSTOMER
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
```

The path must be right, because when I add `http://localhost:8080/Gefaehrdungsbeurteilung_Full/gefaehrdungsbeurteilung_full/server/db/db.script` I see the script file. And inside the script file you see that customer is declared...

Comment: Where is Gefaehrdungsbeurteilung_Full/gefaehrdungsbeurteilung_full/server/db/db.script located?

Comment: Under webcontent and then the path gefaehrdungsbeurteilung_full/se‌​rver/db/ .

Answer (score 0):

You can choose [Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/)- it's on the same stack. Or [SQLLite](https://sqlite.org/).

Answer (score 0):

jdbc:hsqldb:file:/Gefaehrdun... is an absolute path since it starts with /. If you use absolute path, you will need to put your database outside of Tomcat in that exact location.

If you use jdbc:hsqldb:file:Gefaehrdun... (not beginning with /) it will be relative but I'm not sure if it is relative to WEB-INF/classes, tomcat/bin, or other. You'll need to experiment.

Comment: Thank you, I experiment a little bit around :)

Answer (score -2):

You should take a look at **H2**.
It is small an embeddable.

http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Comment: Ok, but when I use the embedded mode of h2 or hsqldb, I always get curios errors when accessing the database. This errors, I don't get when I run the same classes and db as simple java project...

Comment: @Chris Thank you. Now I would guess that the db.script is not executed against the database.

Comment: Ok, but hwat can I do?So my path is wrong?Or what happens here?Because in the internet, I read that normally an embedde DB should also work in a WebApplication

Comment: Sorry, that i can´t help you with that. Read the documentation / tutorials for hsqldb. Find out where the db.script should be. I would guess it should be located in the resources of your applicaion. Remember that the classpath of an webapplication is different from a simple application.